# How to change a variable value on conditional breakpoint in visual studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, breakpoints

Is there any way to change value of variable to on a conditional breakpoint and continue execution.

My code is like this

```
switch(var){ //conditional breakpoint on this line
    case 1:
    break;
...
}
```

I put conditional breakpoint like below 
  `(var == 0 ) || (var ==1)`  is true

So when this breakpoint hits, I want to change `var = 2`, and continue execution.

**What I found:** I found *Action* also, but it only log messages. Is there any way to executing a statement like `var = 2` as Action taken on this conditional breakpoint.

I don't want to change code because building it takes hell lot of time.

**Note:** I am working C++ on Visual studio 2015

Comment: addi that variable  (var) to watch or hover over it. you should be able to assign new value while debugging.

Comment: Quick watch lets you display an arbitrary expression (like x+1). In C++ an assignment is considered an expression.  So try your assignment in quick watch.

Comment: Actually my mentioned code runs under a loop, so its like many times needs to change the value using quick watch, I don't want to do that. I am searching for automatic change of value

Answer (score 10):

In **Log a message to Output Window** write `{my_variable=12345}` the side effect of log output is assigning 12345 to `my_variable`.

Take into account that Log a message can accept and evaluate complex expressions in curly braces.

Comment: Super useful hack! Thanks @anton. This should be the subject of blog posts about advanced debugging techniques. Sometimes it is a huge timesaver to modify a variable with a breakpoint action to try out a fix before coding it or to fork certain logic paths while testing/debugging. Great tip. Not obvious use of the log action and no obvious functionality provided by VS.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify a variable directly in memory to change the execution flow through a [quick watch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0taedcee.aspx) (Shift+F9) or [watch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0taedcee.aspx) window in Visual Studio.

Comment: Actually my mentioned code runs under a loop, so its like many times needs to change the value using quick watch, I don't want to do that. I am searching for automatic change of value

Comment: I don't think there's a way of doing it through visual studio, however, you could take a look at external memory modifying programs, like Cheat Engine, or write such tool by yourself

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in `Tools / Options / Debugging` you have the "Enable Edit and Continue" Enabled/Checked and then you will be able to edit your code while debugging and continue without the need to rebuild or to stop execution.

More information can be found in [**How to: Enable and Disable Edit and Continue**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7yty6a48.aspx)

Comment: While a breakpoint hits and If I add new statement like var =2; then how VS will continue to execute this statement without compiling or linking ?
I think it will first compile or build the new code then continue execution.

Comment: @ashish I am still not sure why you want to debug a code in this special way. What I recommend then is to compile with `var = 2` and then during execution/looping you will be able to change it to 1, 3, 4 etc.

Comment: actually this code runs under a loop and I need to debug it with many different statements, So I was searching for some automatic way of updating value based on condition and also without compiling again and again.

Comment: The only automatic way is to program it yourself. That is why programmers exist .. to automate things :)

Comment: Yes, Now I also thinking the same, that i need to write extra code for all the dependent conditions and set the variables accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This used to work, I can't seem to get it to work now. Worked excellent on loops and also good for altering values without altering the source or the code (and accidently committing it).

```
Conditional break point, break if true

(url = "http://localhost:1234/") != url
```

This works thanks to assignment always returns it's assigned value. This will never be true as url becomes localhost